# How do I call this JS function and pass a parameter through?

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have the following script for my SignalR hub and I'm having trouble on calling my function so that I can pass a parameter through.

```
$(function () {
    var hub = $.connection.commentsHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        function deleteComment(commentId) {
            hub.server.DeleteComment(commentId);
        }
    });
});
```

And then in my list of comments I am trying to call my deleteComment function with this but I get an error stating that deleteComment is not defined.

```
<a onclick="deleteComment(@item.CommentId)">Delete</a>
```

How do I call my deleteComment function?

Or, is there a better way to pass the parameter to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deleteComment()` function is buried within two layers of other functions, so there's no way your inline JavaScript can access it. I suggest (1) taking it out of your `done` callback because there's no reason for it to be there and (2) using unobtrusive JavaScript for this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="delete-comment" data-commentid="@item.CommentId">Delete</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var hub = $.connection.commentsHub;

    function deleteComment(commentId) {
        hub.server.DeleteComment(commentId);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $(".delete-comment").click(function() {
            deleteComment($(this).attr("data-commentid"));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was thinking of using a `.click()` function but I was unsure how to pass the id.